# Split string at pattern like this '),('

Tags: java, android, sqlite

In my Android database application I need to separate a long sql statement contains

```
sql=INSERT INTO table (r1) VALUES ('value1'),('value2'),('value3')... etc
```

into several shorts, I need to split a string at char sequence like `'),('` but seems Java doesn't recognize parentheses.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You should show what you've tried... but I'm assuming you just didn't escape.

Comment: They are special characters in a regular expression. Did you escape them?

Answer (score 1):

You can use \ to split parentheses

```
sql.split("'\\),\\('");
```

Answer (score 0):

`(` and `)` are special characters in regex so you have to escape them by using a `\`. Try

```
"\\),\\("
```

You need 2 backslashes because you need to escape the first one for java.

Answer (score 0):

While writing in java, you can use StringTokenizer and construct the new sql by removing the parenthesis. Use "(" "(" as delimiters.